# looking for js ui widget for filling templates

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I need some kind of js widget, which can fill html templte.
I describe a template (editable or not) in widget's area leaving there some template markup. When widget renders the template, it replaces these marks with controls. If the one, who fills that template clicks on controls, he is being prompted to input some data for those marks, and it is being saved to the template. At this point I use self made gizmo, made of tinymce. It is glitchy and I can hardly customize my control's behavior.

Comment: To this moment the best solution to my idea I could find is to use `substance.io` library.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI is a javascript library which provides below given functionalities:

1. Interactions
2. Widgets
3. Effects
4. Utilities

You can download it here  http://jqueryui.com/